# MapStruct with Spring Boot, annotate generated classes with custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct, spring-profiles

Is there possibility, to annotate class generated by MapStruct, with custom annotation? Currently Im using MapStruct with `componentModel` defined as `"spring"`, like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {}
```

For this interface, class is generated by MapStruct:

```
@Component
public class MyMapperImpl implements MyMapper {}
```

So I can easily inject it. What I want to do, is to annotate generated class with `org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile` annotation, so my generated bean will be in force only if specific profile is defined, is there possibility to inject such annotation, `@Profile("dev")`, to generated class somehow? I was thinking about `org.mapstruct.DecoratedWith` annotation, but I didn't make it working for me

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with the official API. This question is similar to [mapstruct/mapstruct#1427](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1427).

However, there are 2 options that you can try to make it work.

---

#### Option 1 (annotate Mapper)

You can try to annotate `MyMapper` with the `@Profile` annotation, I am not sure whether Spring searches up the inheritance tree and in interface or not

---

#### Option 2 (use internal API)

MapStruct has the [`ModelElementProcessor`](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/blob/master/processor/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/ap/internal/processor/ModelElementProcessor.java) that it used to add the `@Component` annotation. The one for Spring is [`SpringComponentModelElementProcessor`](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/blob/master/processor/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/ap/internal/processor/SpringComponentProcessor.java).

You can provide your own `componentModel` (`spring-dev` for example) that would add the `@Profile` annotation to the generated mapper.

Comment: Option 1 will not work, as `@Profile` excludes beans only, and `MyMapper` is not a bean

Comment: I know that, but I am not sure if Spring checks the annotations in the inheritance. Have you tried it?

Comment: It does not -- I just tried it. I might give option 2 a whirl.